# VSTS "Windows Machine File Copy" task failed: ErrorMessage: 'The network path was not found'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

in VSTS, is it possible to copy files build in VSTS to my local PC? I found a task called "Windows Machine File Copy" and I tried to use it to copy file to my local PC.

There is a machine field:
[machine field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZXrY.png)

And I followed instruction to fill my PC Computer Name here. Then I share a folder named "test1". I want to copy files build in VSTS to "test1" folder in my PC but it caused this error. 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVUVS.png)

Could someone who had experience with this task provide me with some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message '`The network path was not found`' clearly pointed out the problem.

To copy files to local PC which needs the Agent machine can access the local PC, but obviously the **Hosted Agent** cannot access the local PC.

So as a workaround you can try to setup a **private** build agent (the machine which in your local network) for the build: [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts), then grant the permissions for the build agent service account to access another local PC. Then you can copy files...

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try it